# What is correct context for getting workspace maven build output into container build task?

Tags: docker, maven, google-cloud-build

This is similar to [Passing files from Google Cloud Container Builder to Docker build task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48274288/passing-files-from-google-cloud-container-builder-to-docker-build-task) but I can't seem to figure out what the difference is.

I am attempting to build a simple Java program and package it into a Container using Google Cloud Build. I am following mostly along with https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/build-java but using my own repo which is a fork of https://github.com/jchraibi/cloud-native-workshop

```yaml
steps:
  - name: 'maven:3-openjdk-11'
    args:
      - test
      - '-f=code/inventory-quarkus/pom.xml'
    entrypoint: mvn
  - name: 'maven:3-openjdk-11'
    args:
      - package
      - '-f=code/inventory-quarkus/pom.xml'
      - '-Dmaven.test.skip=true'
    entrypoint: mvn
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: 
      - 'build'
      - '-t'
      - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/inventory-quarkus'
      - '--build-arg=JAR_FILE=workspace/code/inventory-quarkus/target/$_BUILD_ARTIFACT'
      - '-f' 
      - 'code/inventory-quarkus/gcp/Dockerfile'
      - '/workspace'
```

The above are the build steps. When the maven package completes, the output is as follows:

```
Step #1: [INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.JarResultBuildStep] Building thin jar: /workspace/code/inventory-quarkus/target/inventory-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
```

However, no matter what combination of copying things and contexts I attempt, I can't seem to find `inventory-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar` anywhere in the filesystem of the Docker build. Note that the Dockerfile lives in a different place than where the target of the build seems to end up.

```
FROM openjdk:11
ARG JAR_FILE=JAR_FILE_MUST_BE_SPECIFIED_AS_BUILD_ARG
RUN find .
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.edg=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

In the logs, interestingly, the output of the `find` command doesn't have a workspace folder at all. I'm sure this has something to do with the fact that the `Dockerfile` is not in the root of the repo, but I just can't find the right invocation.

The link at the beginning of this post to the other thread ended up using an extra step with the `git` image to do some kind of copy, but I don't see why that would be required given all of the Google examples don't have to go through any hoops like that.

The [build containers](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/build-containers) documentation has the following statement:

> If your Dockerfile and source code are in different directories, add -f and the path to the Dockerfile to the list of arguments in the args field:

This is definitely what I'm doing in my build step. It's clearly finding the Dockerfile, because it's processing the find and the copy. I just can't seem to find where/how to get the Maven package step's workspace folder into the builder, or what the source path would be to copy the file from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for your question!  I cloned your repo and added a `cloudbuild.yaml` at the root and added a `Dockerfile` in the `inventory-quarkus/src/main/docker` directory.  I'm sure this isn't exactly the repo structure you're working with, but the concept should carry over.

Essentially, you want to use the [`dir` field](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config#dir) to set your working directory between the steps to more easily pass the data around.  This cloudbuild.yaml worked for me:

```
steps:
  # Test
  - name: 'maven:3-openjdk-11'
    entrypoint: mvn
    args:
      - test
      - '-f=labs/inventory-quarkus/pom.xml'

  # Package
  - name: 'maven:3-openjdk-11'
    entrypoint: mvn
    dir: 'labs/inventory-quarkus'
    args:
      - package 
      - -f=pom.xml 
      - -Dmaven.test.skip=true

  # Docker Build
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    dir: 'labs/inventory-quarkus'
    args: 
      - 'build'
      - '-t'
      - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/inventory-quarkus'
      - '--build-arg=JAR_FILE=target/inventory-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar'
      - '-f' 
      - 'src/main/docker/Dockerfile'
      - '.'
```

I also want to draw your attention to the fact that we now have [Artifact Registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs), if you wanted to store the JAR there and pull it down from the cloud.  You can also use it to store you Docker image.

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks!

I was aware of the artifact repository, but, for the purposes of this test, I wasn't using it. Using it is now the next step :)